# Explanation of a for loop

Tags: c++, c++17

Can someone explain if `col[i]` will increase in the for loop of the below code or not. And how does it even work

```
void dfs(int i) {
    if (i == n) {
        return solve();
    }
    for (int &j = col[i] = 0; j < 6; ++j) {
        dfs(i + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the complete code. Can you share the complete code because I can't see the col array anywhere, except for in the for loop initialization.

Comment: Please do not show the complete code. Instead make a [mre]. (Sorry to contradict you, @ApurvaSingh If you see my point try using `[mre]` in future similar comments.).

Comment: I don't think complete code is necessary given my question. I only wanted to confirm about whether col[i] will increase or not as j++ is executed. Anyways i got it.

Comment: Consider making an answer yourself. I have to admit that while ranting I missed the essential part that `j` is a reference. Allow me to recommend for future questions to more specifically ask what your are focusing. If you had mentioned the "reference" focus, I would not have misunderstood. It was my mistake, but you will always have to help people with avoiding this kind of mistake. Because of my mistake, which indirectly you fixed, I am quite open to see merits in an anwer to this. The downvote is not by me, sorry. Still, if you make the question more focused, it might disappear.

Comment: Also, if you make an answer with your understanding, somebody (maybe me) finds something to explain in more detail. If your answer does not feel good enough to dare making it official, then consider writing your question as "I understand this to work as follows ... Anything to add or correct about that?" That could give you bonus appreciation by people for "own research effort".

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't clear with how references work got how the code works now

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13363/An-Insight-to-References-in-C

great link to read about references made concept crystal clear.